# Return an array with jquery .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a set of checkboxes and want to concatenate only the checked ones into a query string, but for some reason val() only returns the first one.  The jQuery API docs mention that selects can return an array form the .val() function, can I get this same behavior for inputs as well, with a prototype or jquery plugin?

Here's my code:

```
$('.boxes input:checked');
// [ <input type="checkbox" value="val1">, <input type="checkbox" value="val2">, <input type="checkbox" value="val3"> ]
$('.boxes input:checked').val();
// "val1"
```

Ideally the second console output would be:

```
$('.boxes input:checked').val();
// [ "val1", "val2", "val3" ]
```

Comment: Your checkboxes don't have the same name, so jquery has no way to know they're associated. Just my initial hunch

Comment: `.val()` only returns an array for a `<select multiple>` element.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm looking to add functionality to .val() rather than change the existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val` returns an array of selected values for `select` elements that have `multiple` attribute, for other elements it returns the value of the first element in the set. You can use the `map` method:

```
var values = $('.boxes input:checked').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get();
```

You can also define a method:

```
$.fn.vals = function() {
    var first = this.get(0);
    if ( this.length === 0 ) return [];

    if ( first.tagName === 'SELECT' && first.multiple ) {
        return this.val();
    }

    return this.map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
}
// ...
var values = $('.boxes input:checked').vals();
```

Comment: This is true, but I'd like to overload the existing val behavior to return the mapped version for inputs as well.

Comment: I'd rather fix this at the prototype level than have a bunch of map functions all over the place.  Makes it a lot more readable.